# Is implementing search for symbols impossible?

Tags: search-engine

I tried to Google for symbol `£` but surprised with a response

> Your search - £ - did not match any
>   documents.

'£' must be a part of some font, any special reason that its not considered by Google ?

*EDIT:*

Even [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%C2%A3) doesn't give any results...

Comment: You can use http://www.symbolhound.com to search for symbols. StackOverflow and other sites are indexed; however, it is mainly targeted at programming-related sites.

Answer (score 1):

It's not impossible, but symbols are usually excluded from the haystack pool since the words are usually far more important to users.